# Passing pointer to non-static member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I've got a non-static member function of a class:

```
int Band::overlap(unsigned dim, const double *x, void *data_p, unsigned fdim,
        double *retval){

    int *data = (int*) data_p;
    // data[0] = m; data[1] = n; data[2] = k_ind; data[3] = b
    cmplx result = (this->U(x[0], x[1], x[2], data[2], data[0])).adjoint()
                 *  this->U(x[0], x[1], x[2], data[2] + data[3], data[1]);
    retval[0] = result.real();
    retval[1] = result.imag();
    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to pass it to [cubature](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature), which requires it to be of the following form:

```
int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval)
```

I considered using [std::mem_fn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), but if I use:

```
auto bla = std::mem_fn(&Band::overlap);
```

my call would be:

```
bla(band_obj, ....)
```

which cubature doesn't accept. I then considered using lambdas, but I read that I can only convert non-capture lambdas, therefore I can't capture band_obj.

I realize, that variations of this question have been asked, I tried them und non of them seem to work.

Comment: Look for `std::bind`...

Comment: @barakmanos Bind would not work. `f` is a pointer to a C function, e.g.: with no `this` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

We want `f` to be a pointer to non-static member function *and* to be called as a regular function - without the `this` pointer. `std::function`, `lambda` and all of these solutions would not work - we still need to pass their `this` somehow.

### The Solution

`Cubature` provides the `fdata` argument to pass it to your function, we could use it to pass the `this` pointer:

```
int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval) {
    Band *band = static_cast<Band*>(fdata);
    return band->overlap(ndim, x, fdim, fval);
}
```

And then call `hcubature` with the `this` parameter as `fdata`:

```
hcubature(1, f, static_cast<void*>(band), 
          3, xmin, xmax, 0, 0, 1e-4, ERROR_INDIVIDUAL, &val, &err);
```

Comment: A variation of this worked. My *fdata now is a static_cast of a tuple containing <band, ...regular fdata...> this seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Cubator it says:

> The FDATA argument of F is equal to the FDATA argument passed to
>   hcubature—this can be used by the caller to pass any additional
>   information through to F as needed

So you  can create a static proxy function:

```
static int Band::overlap_static(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval) 
{
  ((Band *)fdata)->overlap(ndim, x, fdim, fval);
}
```

You then can call `hcubature` with the current `Band` pointer as third argument and `Band::operlap_static` as the function pointer. Of course then you gave to manage `*data` differently.

Comment: You can do this in a lambda in-place in the call. Since you cast from fdata and have no capture for anything else, it'll convert to a C-compatible function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Cubature is a C function that expects a C function pointer as a parameter.

There is absolutely nothing whatsoever in C++ that can make a C-compatible function pointer from a member function, an `std::mem_fn`, an `std::function`, a lambda, or anything else except a plain non-member `extern "C"` function pointer.

You can write a plain non-member `extern "C"` function and make it use a `Band*` value passed to it as a `void*.

```
Band* band;
hcubature_v(fdim, overlap_adapter, static_cast<void*>(band), ...);

extern "C" int overlap_adapter(unsigned ndim, unsigned npts, 
                               const double *x, void *fdata,
                               unsigned fdim, double *fval) 
{
    Band* band = static_cast<Band*>(fdata);
    ... band->overlap(...) ...
}
```

Of course the first thing to do is to write a C++ wrapper template around `hcubature_v` that accepts any C++ callable object.

Comment: " There is absolutely nothing whatsoever in C++ that can make a C-compatible function pointer" -> You can implicitly convert a lambda to a c-compatible function pointer if it has no captures. Try `signal(SIGTERM, [](void*){...});` for example.

Comment: @dascandy non-capturing-lambda is in other words just a regular plain function.

Comment: @dascandy I just realized that formally this is not the case. Such a function pointer will not have C linkage and thus will not be C compatible, though most implementation will let you get away with it.

Comment: It will convert into a function pointer type of the appropriate calling convention. Linking is only relevant when you'd need to link to it - but as it's an argument being passed in, that's not this case.

Comment: @dascandy my copy of the standard says "has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function with C++ language linkage". A non-normative note says "a particular language linkage may be associated with a particular form of representing names of objects and functions with external linkage, or with a particular calling convention" and it's the only place where the standard talks about calling conventions.

Comment: @n.m. so it's allowed to make it incompatible. Good to know - although currently all compilers don't use this. I'd expect a compile error though in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not going to work.

`void *data_p` is part of the argument to pass state, but `Band::overlap` uses both `void *data_p` **and** `Band* this` for that purpose.

Solution:

```
/*static*/ int Band::overlap(
      unsigned dim, const double *x, void *data_p, unsigned fdim, double *retval)
{
    return static_cast<Band*>(data_p)->overlap(dim,x,fdim, retval);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `std::function`:

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
using std::placeholders::_3;
using std::placeholders::_4;
using std::placeholders::_5;

using fn_signiture = int(unsigned, const double*, void*, unsigned, double*)

std::function<fn_signiture> pointer = std::bind(&Band::overlap,this,_1, _2, _3, _4, _5);
//"this" can be replaced with a pointer to a specific instance of a Band.
```

I chose to use a few `using` statements in order to clean up the code.

Comment: This doesn't work:  note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::function<fn_signiture>' (aka
      'function<int (unsigned int, const double *, void *, unsigned int, double *)>') to 'integrand' (aka 'int (*)(unsigned int, const double *, void *, unsigned
      int, double *)') for 2nd argument
int hcubature(unsigned fdim, integrand f, void *fdata,